# How to provide links to social sites for an android phonegap app from within the app?

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, cordova

This might be probably a bizarre question that someone might have asked in history of this platform. But its better to ask and gain knowledge as much as possible.

I am total noob to app development, hence started my way with phonegap and jQuery Mobile. Anyways, the app I'm targeting to build is merely a static website converted to an app. But for a marketing trick, I would like to have some social "shout-outs" from the app itself to facebook, twitter, etc. for app's link on google play (***Example***: Hey, I have just started using this app, and its awesome, download here-> the link)

My Main question however is, is there any way to accomplish this? If yes, I'll be grateful to know. However, if it still not exists, I being a total noob, would like to know how to just post simple text on social sites (what steps to follow) from the phonegap app itself without crashing it. (Note: I am using the cordova-eclipse platform and not the phonegap build).

Thanks in advance
Cheers.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely possible. Take a look at the [Facebook PhoneGap Plugin](https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-facebook-connect/tree/master) and the [Twitter PhoneGap](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Twitter) plugin. Once you get those figured out then you can just have users hit "share" or something like that and then make a post with a link to your application's store link.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll be implementing them soon after I have done my data entry work for the app, and get back to you in case of any difficulty. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the href to `"market://details?id="+appName` where appName is the official package name of the app. For example, to open the facebook app page on the playstore it would be:

```
window.location.href="market://details?id=com.facebook.katana";
```

Edit: ***Made a better example using facebook app id.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is a great lead when I was absolutely clueless. I'll be implementing this when the app's in the finishing stages. Thanks